# Why does this make file only call one target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to make and I am trying to make a super simple build script. This is what I have:

```
.PHONY: all main
all:
    mkdir -p build && cd build

main: main.o install
    g++ -o main main.o

main.o: ../src/main.cpp
    g++ -c ../src/main.cpp

.PHONY: install
install: 
    mkdir -p build
    mv main.o build 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r build/
```

I would expect it to call `all` followed by `main`. In actuality, here's what happens:

```
$ make
mkdir -p build && cd build
```

Only `all` is called and `main` is not ran. Why? I have `main` as a prerequisite after `all` in the `.PHONY` line. And help?

Comment: The .PHONY line isn't a real rule, so they aren't real prerequisites. It just marks those targets as being phony. If you want "all" built and then "main" built you have to create a real rule that has those targets eg. `really-all: all main`. Note that your makefile still won't do what you expect to do because `cd` in recipe only affects that recipe line. It doesn't affect make or any other recipe line.

Comment: Typically you would add a target `build` with recipe `mkdir -p $@`, and then add that as an [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) prerequisite to `main`.   You would prepend `build/` to main.o to ensure it built in the correct directory, rather than cd'ing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.PHONY` is not a real target (it is a special make construct), and does not cause its prerequisites to be run.   Instead, the first real target mentioned is `all`, and if you just type `make`, it will invoke the `all` as the default target.  Because `all` is not dependent on anything, it is the only target that is run.

You can add a line at the very top:

```
default: all main
```

which will cause both `all` and `main` to run (don't forget to add `default` to `.PHONY`.  Notice though that you are not guaranteed that `all` will run before main.   If you want to guarantee this, you would also have to add

`main: all`

which would force `all` to be run before `main`